# ActionScript 3.0 Document Class not extending to MovieClip or Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, movieclip, extends, document-class

Can I have a document class which is not extending to either sprite or movieclip, but this is extending to an another class which is inherited by Sprite?

I have to access stage in document class, but I am getting stage as null object reference.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: may be try to handle `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event? have a look: http://fromzerotoas3hero.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/added-vs-addedtostage.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have already tried this, still getting stage as null. Can you give me some example in which document class does not extend to Movieclip or sprite.

Comment: Are you trying to access the stage within the constructor?

Comment: No I am trying to access stage in added to stage function..